# Optional group in Regex returns too many matches

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match only values (i.e. 2.699.230,20) from an input on a C# Regex class.

I use `"(\\.?[0-9]){2,}\\,[0-9]{2}"` and it matches desired values `5.000,00`, `2.699.230,20`, `1.000.000,00`, etc. The `{2,}` is to only match values above `999,99`.

But there's also other values on the same input that i want to match. They are always `1.000` or above, but the difference is that it don't have the decimal `,00` part. Examples: `4.541.087`, `8.997.434`.

So i put the last part of the regex a binary (0 or 1 times present) option (added `(...)?` around the decimal part:

`"(\\.?[0-9]){2,}(\\,[0-9]{2})?"`, but now this matches hundreds of numbers, including `18`, `1.0`, `1.5.2`, `8854`, etc.

So, how can i make the decimal part optional, so it matches both `1.000,00` and `1.000`?

Comment: Try [`new Regex(@"\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+(?:,\d{2})?")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d(%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%7b3%7d)%2b(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b2%7d)%3f&i=values+5.000%2c00%2c+2.699.230%2c20%2c+1.000.000%2c00%2c+etc.++999%2c99%0d%0aincluding+18%2c+1.0%2c+1.5.2%2c+8854%2c+etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you only want to get numbers that have a `.` as thousand separator in them with optional 2 digits in the fractional part.

Use

```
@"\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+(?:,\d{2})?\b"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d(%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%7b3%7d)%2b(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b2%7d)%3f%5cb&i=values+5.000%2c00%2c+2.699.230%2c20%2c+1.000.000%2c00%2c+etc.++999%2c99%0d%0aincluding+18%2c+1.0%2c+1.5.2%2c+8854%2c+etc.).

*Details*:

- `\b` - leading word boundary (may be replaced with `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind to disallow only digit before...)
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{3})+` - 1 or more sequences of a dot and 3 digits (**NOTE**: if you change `+` with `*`, it will match values below `1.000`)
- `(?:,\d{2})?` -  an optional sequence of a `,` and 2 digits.
- `\b` - trailing word boundary (may be replaced with `(?!\d)` negative lookbahead to disallow only digit after the number).

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/rihFGt):

```
var re = @"\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+(?:,\d{2})?\b"; 
var str = "values 5.000,00, 2.699.230,20, 1.000.000,00, etc.  999,99 including 18, 1.0, 1.5.2, 8854, etc"; 
var res = Regex.Matches(str, re)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(p => p.Value)
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", res));
```

Comment: (?:\.\d{3})+ should be (?:\.\d{3})? so the regex can also mach 999 or 999.99

Comment: another improvement need to be done is to avoid 000.012,10 to be matched
\d{1,3} -> [1-9]\d{0,2}

Comment: @JianpingLiu: I think *is to only match values above `999,99`* means OP does not want values below 1.000

Comment: Worked perfectly. I understood your rationale completely. Can you just point out why my enclosure of the decimal part in a binary group didn't work? Perhaps add it to your answer.

Comment: As for `000.012,10`, a lookahead can be added - `\b(?!0+\.)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+(?:,\d{2})?\b`

Comment: @MrBilly: The enclosure was correct, but `(\\.?[0-9]){2,}` matches 2 or more sequences of an optional dot and 1 digit. That means it could match 2 or digits and then an empty string. It matched all digit chunks of more than 1 digit.

Comment: @MrBilly the problem is from the first part (\\.?[0-9]){2,}